# Use KeyVault references in Function Keys

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have an HTTP triggered function, and have configured it to use KeyVault to store my keys, by using the following application settings:

```
AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType = keyvault  
AzureWebJobsSecretStorageKeyVaultUri = https://nameof-keyvault.vault.azure.net/
```

There is an identity set for the function to access the KeyVault.

I'm trying to secure my function using Function Keys.

I've added my function key, and can see it's stored in KeyVault. When I use the key to authenticate against the function, it executes.

However, when I look in the portal, I can *see* the secrets:

[image: function keys - show values]

I was expecting to see KeyVault references here.

If I manually change them to KeyVault references, it no longer works (auth fails)

Is there a way to hide these keys from the portal, and only surface them out of KeyVault?

Comment: I believe your ask is how & where to store the Azure Function Access Level (Authorization) Keys other than in the Function Keys (Developer Menu - as above) and in Key Vault!

Comment: The Function Keys are being stored in KeyVault (I can see them) - but they're being visually surfaced in the portal of the Function - which isn't what I want